# Fixed position content larger than the document or window/device height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

NOTE: I've modified the subject and some of the content of this post.

I'm writing a responsive menu that is `position:fixed` and `overflow-y:scroll`.

The menu height can be greater than the height of the device screen, and I'm trying to find a work around so the menu is scrollable, regardless of either the document or the window/device height

I've put together a little demo here:
http://s.codepen.io/onebitrocket/fullpage/iysLI?

and here's the codepen iframed link:
http://codepen.io/onebitrocket/full/iysLI

Unless I missing something, I don't think a vertical fixed position menu is possible. Mainly due to the height of the menu being larger than the height of the device window.

Is there a solution to enable this?

-- Additionally
My initial question was this
The iOS bottom 'nav' bar seems to have a reserved touch area, which conflicts with the last elements in my menu - see the image below.

This prevents me from clicking on the last item in my menu.

Is there a fix for this?

[image: The iOS7 Safari bottom 'nav' bar]

Comment: try giving padding from bottom to your `ul` . or provide your code to get better answers .

Comment: I would wrap the whole menu inside another wrapper with position fixed, top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; and overflow-y: scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/2FfsB/

Comment: @JonasGrumann - thanks, thats' getting there. I've added in a .active` class for the '.mainnav' wrapper when the nav is toggled to slidedown